# CSS - reCAPTCHA image width

Tags: css, width, recaptcha

I need to specify two different widths for "#recaptcha_image"
As the recatcha image is placed in #recaptcha_image div, I had added custom width in my CSS, as following:

```
#recaptcha_image img {width: 200px !important; height: 38px !important; }
```

As I can not change the DIV id, how can i specify the second width for #recaptcha_image in the same CSS file?
I can use only ONE CSS file because i have a common header, which includes CSS file.

Thanks.

Comment: @karolis, if you want to include reCAPTCHA, you place an empty `recaptcha_image` div, in which reCAPCTAH image is loaded. http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html

Comment: ok, so I think you can put them in additional divs with different classes or ids. Can't you?

Comment: @Karolis, I figured out that already. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class in the CSS with a different width:

`#recaptcha_image img.newWidth {width: 100px }`

You would then have to add that class to the element at the required time.

I know you didn't mention JavaScript in the question, but you could also use JavaScript to change the width when necessary by using `element.style.width = '100px';`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. reCAPTCHA is loaded by placing an empty div, like: `<div id="recaptcha_image"></div>`. So how i would call the img.newWidth class in it?

Comment: As james said with jquery. `$('#recaptcha_image img').addClass('newWidth');` Do this when the page has finished loading.

Comment: @Roman -it would be nice if you could share the solution with us. I'm still trying to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Following removes the fixed attributes from the ASPX control and adds a couple of classes for formatting.

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
    var cell = $('#recaptcha_response_field');
    cell.removeAttr('style');
    cell = $('.recaptcha_image_cell');
    cell.addClass('CaptchaCell');
    cell.removeAttr('width');
    cell = $('#recaptcha_image');
    cell.addClass('CaptchaWidth');
    cell.removeAttr('style');
    cell = $('#recaptcha_image img');
    cell.addClass('CaptchaWidth');
    cell.removeAttr('width');
    cell.removeAttr('height');
    cell.removeAttr('style');
});
```

This is the CSS to reduce the size of the Captcha cells after the above is applied.  Scaling for media is left as an exercise for you...

```
/* Captcha smallest settings */
.CaptchaCell {
    width: 202px;
}

.CaptchaWidth {
    width: 200px;
    height: 57px;
}
.recaptchatable {
    width: 252px;
}
#recaptcha_response_field {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #3c3c3c;
}

#recaptcha_tagline {
    display:none;
}
#recaptcha_logo {
    display:none;
}
```